Grothendieck topoi as a constructive property
This question is inspired by Homotopy type theory, but I believe it can be thought about also in other constructive foundations.
In HoTT the question could be stated as follows:
Given a definition of Grothendieck topos $C$ as a geometric embedding into presheaves on some category $site$, call it $S : Category \rightarrow Type$. This is obviously a structure, rather than property. Is there a property $P : Category \rightarrow Type$ such that $P$ is a homotopy proposition with $P(C)$ and $S(C)$ implying each other?
In general here is an idea working in usual (set-based) CLASSICAL category theory, to obtain similar behavior;
Using well-ordering of cardinals and Giraud's theorem, the structural bit of Giraud's theorem is the accessiblity part of local presentability. To obtain something property-like with choice, one could pick the least $\kappa$, for which $C$ is $\kappa$-accessible.
This should possibly work in impredicative HoTT with choice, but I havent checked whether the truncated choice in HoTT is actually enough.
Are there other classically equivalent characterizations of Grothendieck topoi that could be made reasonably property-like and potentially constructive?
One definition I wonder about in particular is the definition as a Set-bounded topos as this definition relativizes. Here the usual definitions involve picking a bound or picking a fibered generating family, which there could be many. All the equivalent characterizations I am aware of, of bounded geometric morphisms are structure-like.
Here are options I wondered about that I failed to determine truth of:

Is there always a unique standard site? I dont think so but I am not aware of a counterexample.
Does the full subcategory of category of (standard?) sites, on sites which result in the same Grothendieck topos $T$, have initial or terminal objects?

I doubt this is possible and an attempt to make it precise metatheoretically for HoTT + any consistent rules that would have normalization, would be the following conjecture:
There can be no type family $GrothProp : Category \rightarrow Type$ in any constructive strongly normalizing extension of HoTT; such that $(\forall C. isHProp(GrothProp(C))) \times  (\forall C. GrothProp(C) \rightarrow Groth(C)) \times (\forall C. Groth(C) \rightarrow GrothProp(C))$,
where $Groth$ is the definition in terms of site + geometric embedding. In other words a very nice propositional definition of Grothendieck topoi would be a strong sort of constructive taboo in HoTT.

You shouldn’t use well-ordered cardinals if you want to work constructively. Giraud’s theorem is basically constructive except for this. Small sites are not by any means unique or canonical. Consider studying Part B of [Sketches of an elephant] to see what works well in the relative setting.

@ZhenLin I have studied the bounded ones and the options in the Elephant all seem structure-like. I should make it clearer, that the examples of what would the property-like form look like are all classical and does do not actually answer the question.

Making things structure-like is usually how constructive redefinitions work. The only case I know where there is a canonical site is the localic one. Otherwise there seems to be an arbitrary cutoff to keep the site small.

Yes, that's indeed the case and yet some constructive redefinitions still end up being essentially unique. I wonder if something similar can be done in the grothendieck topos case, my hopes from reading the literature are not particularly high, but maybe there's at least a nice counterexample?

I don't see a sufficiently precise conjecture to offer a counterexample. The phenomenon of Morita equivalence (much promoted by Caramello) implies not only are sites non-unique, they can be non-unique in ways that have interesting consequences.

I dont know how to state sufficiently precise conjure outside HoTT; in HoTT the conjecture can be made precise, there is no type family GrothProp : Category -> Type; such that forall C, isHProp(GrothProp(C)) , forall C. GrothProp(C) -> Groth(C) and forall C. Groth(C) -> GrothProp(C), where Groth is the usual definition in terms of site + geometric embedding.

Is that really what you mean? You can probably construct a model where there is such a type family, with the help of a sufficiently powerful choice principle (pick once and for all for every equivalence class of Grothendieck toposes a site presentation; the site will need to be just big enough so that every automorphism of the topos can be realised as an automorphism of the site).

@ZhenLin yes but note the fact I can not go the choice way as I am trying to keep the HoTT constructive, see my edit to question

One possible answer is that in his 1981 paper "Notions of topos", Ross Street proved that with a fixed universe to define "small" and "large", if $C$ is a locally small and "moderate" category, the latter meaning that its set of objects is large but no larger than the size of the universe itself, then it is a Grothendieck topos if and only if its Yoneda embedding $C \to [C^{\rm op}, \rm Set]$ (which exists because $C$ is locally small, although $[C^{\rm op}, \rm Set]$ is not locally small) has a left exact left adjoint.  In Street's words, "the only canonical choice of site is the topos itself."
If memory serves, Street's proof is not very constructive, involving a transfinite induction over all small ordinals, perhaps even well-ordering the objects of the category.  But perhaps there is some constructive analogue; I haven't thought about it.

I recall the lex-totality being subtle even without constructive considerations, let me find the reference. But I think that's covered by the moderateness.

IIRC his condition is actually a bit more general than moderateness, but it's implied by moderateness.

You can drop the well-ordering of the category's objects, by techniques in the paper I hope to finish with Martti Karvonen. But for now see things (talks/blog posts) by me under the name "how to be concrete if you don't have a choice". I don't think you can drop EM so easily though. We remove AC, but need booleanness. And we need a stratification of the objects into set-sized levels, a la the cumulative hierarchy...

BTW here's the reference for Ross's paper: Bulletin of the Australian Mathematical Society , Volume 23 , Issue 2 , April 1981 , pp. 199 - 208 DOI: https://doi.org/10.1017/S000497270000705X
